# How do I replace the Azure console with cmd?

Tags: cmd

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scXS9.png)

I encounter this when I write cmd. How can I fix ?

Answer (score 0):

Trivial way to fire up the cmd console is to tap <kbd>Windows key</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>, type `cmd` and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just typing `cmd`, type `%ComSpec%` and press Enter.

Alternatively, you could type `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` and press Enter.